# how much does facebook denormalize their databases to break things up by network and therefore shrink the tables and speed the system?

Tags: database, facebook

any bit of info will be helpful here.  or does anybody else huge do something interesting here too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read up on [Database Sharding](http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/) aka [Shared-Nothing Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture)